# Is it possible to (recursively) "introspect" nested C structs using x-macros?

Tags: c, reflection, macros, preprocessor, x-macros

I was reading this article ([Struct iteration through (ab)use of the preprocessor](https://natecraun.net/articles/struct-iteration-through-abuse-of-the-c-preprocessor.html)), where the author uses x-macros and `offsetof` to add metadata to structs which would allow their members to be easily serialized, accessed by name, etc. But it's only implemented for primitive struct elements.

Is it possible to expand this to structs containing nested struct, also? I.e. something which would allow simple de/serialialization of something like:

```
struct some_struct {
   int x, y, z;
}; 

struct data {
   int number;
   struct some_struct something;
};
```

I've noticed the author states this at the beginning:

> At this stage, the structs only consist of primitive elements (int, float, char, etc). *Handling nested structs, unions, bitfields and pointers would require additional work* (that may be the subject of a future post).

Is something like this possible using the C preprocessor?

**(Clarification)**

To make it clearer, I'd like to see if there is a way which would allow me to:

a) define the `struct`, and
  b) create meta data for textual serialization/deserialization

if possible in one step.

Comment: Well, "recursively" and "macros" are never working together.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: well, I know there are ways to get something like [list "iteration"](https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro), so perhaps the title is misleading.

Comment: The parentheses are wrong. It should be "**ab**use". That's an XY problem, use code-generation to accomplish this. Such code will eventually leave you in macro hell for debugging.

Comment: @Olaf: do you know of a tool which can generate a set of structs with textual de/serializers for C? Most things I've found are related to C++ templates.

Comment: Yes I do. Tool recommendations are off-topic. Just that: you seem not have searched well. (and it is not that complicated to write a small Python program to generate such code).

Comment: Can't you just call the nested struct serializer from the parent struct serializer (note: I did not read the linked article)?

Comment: I don't understand the question but it sounds like something really cool. Did you manage to do it?

Comment: @étale-cohomology: we ended up using protocol buffers, their tool generates both structs and serialization code from .proto files. We also used some code generation for other things instead of xmacros, because it makes everyone's life much easier when there is an actual .c/.h file you can open, view, and step-through while debugging. Debugging through macros is a real pain in the ass, and code generation allows you to do much more than you would be able with macros only

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing! I've considered using protobufs before, but somehow I always decide to roll my own serialization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that you asked for is implemented here https://github.com/alexanderchuranov/Metaresc

Here is a sample app:

```
#include <metaresc.h>

TYPEDEF_STRUCT (some_struct_t,
                int x,
                int y,
                int z,
                );

TYPEDEF_STRUCT (data_t,
                int number,
                (struct some_struct_t, something),
                );  

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  data_t data = { 1, { 2, 3, 4 } };
  MR_PRINT ("data = ", (data_t, &data));
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Expected output:

```
data = {
  .number = 1,
  .something = {
    .x = 2,
    .y = 3,
    .z = 4
  }
}
```

Comment: A couple years ago clang added a new feature that also addresses this use case https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-dump-struct